# Can a GIT branch have a subset of data?

Tags: java, spring, git, github

I am trying to find out if a GIT branch can have a subset of the project data like the example below.

I am working on a java, spring, maven project and my source is at

```
src/main/java
```

and my JSP pages are at:

```
src/main/webapp
```

we are thinking of outsource the JSP pages to a diff group but we don't want them changing the java code so we are trying to think if we can map a branch with just

```
src/main/webapp
```

and then merge it back in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to export the history of that `webapp` directory an an independent git repo, used within the current (parent) repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**.
That way, you are *sure* the external contributor doesn't modify any source except the ones you want.

The other (simpler) way is to create a branch dedicated for the other group of contributors, and accept merges only through [pull request](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project) (that you would reject if any file outside of `webapp` is modified)

Comment: @JohnNY mainly in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules)